# Normal Subgroup of Direct Product Implies Each Component Normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

If $N_1 \times N_2 \times ... \times N_p$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2 \times ... \times G_p$, is it true that $N_i \unlhd G_i$ for each value of $i$?

Conjugating an arbitrary $(n_1, n_2, ..., n_p) \in N_1 \times N_2 \times ... \times N_p$ by $(g,1, ..., 1) \in G_1 \times G_2 \times ... \times G_p$ gives $(gn_1g^{-1}, n_2, ..., n_p)$, which must be an element of $N_1 \times N_2 \times ... \times N_p$ by normality of $N_1 \times N_2 \times ... \times N_p$ in $G_1 \times G_2 \times ... \times G_p$.

So $gn_1g^{-1} \in N_1$ for an arbitrary $g \in G_1$ and $n_1 \in N_1$, in other words $N_1$ is closed under conjugation from $G_1$ hence $N_1 \unlhd G_1$, and since we can show this for any $N_i$ and $G_i$, each component of the normal subgroup direct product must be normal to the corresponding component of the group direct product.  Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: try conjugating by $(g,1,1,\dots,1)\in G_1\times\cdots\times G_p$.

Comment: What have you tried? What information do you have at your disposal to attempt an answer?

Comment: I wish that it was true, but I don't believe it to be.  I've spent a while trying to come up with a counterexample but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Normality doesn’t mean that $\forall n \in N\, \forall g \in G\, (gng^{-1}=n)$, normality means that $\forall n \in N\, \forall g \in G\, (gng^{-1} \in N)$.

Comment: @azif00 I think I fixed my reasoning to read what you were talking about